# Проверка буквы на регистр в Javascript, код не больше 9 символов

Tags: javascript

Решал задачу на codewars.com, нужно проверить является ли буква заглавной, код не должен превышать 9 символов. Объясните решения.

```
f=s=>s<{}
```

или

```
f=_=>_<f
```

или

```
f=Z=>Z<=f
```

Comment: Во-первых, стрелочные функции. Во-вторых, при сравнениях строки со странными объектами объекты преобразуются в строку. Дальше сами догадаетесь?

Comment: Это прикольно, но не надо писать такой код в реальной жизни!)

Answer (score 2):

В `js` у каждого символа есть свой код. Код представляется числом, поэтому мы можем сравнивать символы не только с помощью `===`, но так же и `<`,`>`. По сути, когда идет сравнение строк, сравниваются их код. Поэтому один символ может быть больше другого символа

Теперь смотрите:

> одна и та же буква в нижнем и верхнем регистре
>   будет иметь разные коды

```
// codePointAt - вернет код символа, номер которого мы передали для строки.
"z".codePointAt(0); // 122
"Z".codePointAt(0); // 90
```

Видно, что самая последняя заглавная буква имеет код 90, а самая последняя строчная буква имеет 122. Так же есть спецсимволы, которые так же входят в диапазон между 90 и 122.

Теперь, рассмотрим решения:

```
f=s=>s<{}
```

Здесь происходит магия приведения в `js`, когда разные типы приводятся к одинаковому неявно. `{}` будет приведено к строке, что даст нам `[object Object]`, и получится, что у нас символ будет сравниваться с этой строкой ( причем только с первым символом )

```
// код у [ = 91, поэтому он всегда будет больше, 
// чем любая прописная буква и меньше чем любая строчная
f=s=>s<'['
```

Вторые два способа по сути одинаковые. Опять же символ сравниваем со строкой, только теперь в строке сама функция сравнения. Первым символом будет аргумент функции `_` или же `Z`.

```
f=_=>_<f
f=Z=>Z<=f
```

А дальше все как обычно, `_` - разрешенный символ для названия переменных, поэтому можем использовать его в объявлении функции и его код 95, поэтому тоже самое что и с `[`. C `Z` все наоборот, это последняя прописная буква, поэтому она больше любых других прописных букв, но меньше чем любая строчная.

*Символ `<=`, это что бы сама Z тоже попадала в условие*